# Using Task.Wait() for waiting while task is finished (even if it already finished)

Tags: c#

Can I use `task.Wait();` like that? Note that when I call `task.Wait` the task is probably already finished.

And probably you can suggest better pattern.

```
class A {
    private Task task1;
    private Task task2;

    ...
    public void Connect() {
        stayConnected = true;
        task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(....,
            while (stayConnected) {
                ....
            }
            LongRunning);
        task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(....,
            while (stayConnected) {
                ....
            }
            LongRunning);
    }

    private volatile bool stayConnected;

    // should be synchronous. when return everything should be disconected
    public void Disconnect() {
        stayConnected = false;
        task1.Wait();
        task1 = null;
        task2.Wait();
        task2 = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CancellationToken` and `Task.WaitAll(...)` to do this...

```
public class A
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task task1;
    private Task task2;

    public void Connect()
    {
        task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeWork, tokenSource.Token);
        task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeWork, tokenSource.Token);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        Task.WaitAll(task1,task2);
    }

    public void SomeWork(object o)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)o;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("working...");
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on managed threads check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx) article on MSDN. Enjoy :D

Comment: why cancellationtoken is better than just "volatile boolean"? in general i prefer "easy to port to c++" code.

Comment: I think `CancellationToken` should be used when you want to cancel a `Task` prematurely. I think that's not the case here. Also, canceling the `Task` properly (which you didn't do) would mean `WaitAll()` would throw an exception.

Comment: You can certainly use `volatile` if you want to keep it simple.

Comment: @svick why does it throw an exception?

Comment: @Alechandro Because the `Task`s would be canceled. `Wait()` and `WaitAll()` throw an exception when you wait on a canceled `Task`.

Comment: Do not use `volatile`, e.g. see the famous Joe Duffy blog post http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/06/13/volatile-reads-and-writes-and-timeliness/ If you really want to use a `bool` flag, wrap it around the simple `lock` statement (and some lock object).

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Wait()` should just return `true` if the task is completed, so sure you can. However, you should better use waiting with timeout or `TimeSpan` parameter if you have actions inside of `while { }` loop that can possibly cause a freeze.

Comment: `Task.Wait()` without a timeout doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a reasonable approach to me. You could improve it a bit by using `Task.WaitAll()` but that won't change much.

Also, I wouldn't set the fields to `null` unless I had good reason to do it. Yeah, those `Task`s are not useful for anything anymore, but they are also almost free.